# Toggling minor modes based on other minor modes

Tags: init-file, hooks, minor-mode

I wrote a function to enable some minor modes when another minor mode is enabled:

```lisp
(defun prose-mode()
  (display-line-numbers-mode)
  (variable-pitch-mode))
```

I added `prose-mode` as a hook for `olivetti-mode`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'olivetti-mode-hook 'prose-mode)
```

The hook is working fine and `prose-mode` gets ivoked on `M-x olivetti-mode`.

However, when I do that again to disable the mode, the line numbers don't reappear. `variable-pitch-mode` is toggling and I get my monospaced font back.

In general, is this the right way to do what I'm trying to do?
Inside `prose-mode`, should I check for the current minor mode using a conditional statement to enable/disable the other modes?

Comment: If I do understand correctly, you're loading some stuff using the hook, which is run only when activated.

Comment: Elisp tag shouldn't used here, please, check [elisp tag info](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info)

Comment: @Muihlinn I am enabling other minor modes using the hook, which is run only when activated.

Comment: I meant that disabling `olivetti-mode` won't run the hook, if you mean that the line numbers doesn't toggle when you run again `prose-mode` you should use `(display-line-numbers-mode 'toggle)` instead.

Comment: The function name `prose-mode` is misleading, as it's is not a minor mode, minor mode is usually defined via `define-minor-mode`, a better name is `sixter-olivetti-mode-setup` (?) and you can detect if the olivetti mode is on or off via the variable `olivetti-mode`.

Comment: Thanks @Muihlinn. That fixed my issue.

Comment: My pleasure, but listen to xuchunyang, your function name goes against emacs conventions.

Comment: @Muihlinn Yes, I did that. That was a temporary dummy name. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As xuchunyang noted in comments, your shouldn't use `prose-mode` to name a function that doesn't define a mode, so you could define your function like this:

```lisp
(defun sixter-olivetti-mode-setup()
 "Load additional stuff with olivetti-mode."
  (display-line-numbers-mode 'toggle)
  (variable-pitch-mode)
)
```

Note that `display-line-numbers-mode`, accepts an optional argument to specify what you want to do. `toggle` is what your need in your case. You can ask for its documentation typing <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `display-line-numbers-mode`.

Then add it to the hook as you already did:

```lisp
(add-hook 'olivetti-mode-hook 'sixter-olivetti-mode-setup)
```